# Starting to code OpenGL in Qt

Tags: qt, macos, opengl, glut

I intend to create OpenGL 3D applications on Mac OS X (32bit) preferably on Qt Creator.
Are there any specific tutorials?!

It seems I have to change many parts of the code for Windows tutorials to get them to work on OS X gcc.

Snow Leopard 10.6.6

Qt SDK 4.7

Comment: Did you take a look in the OpenGL examples provided by QT after installing it? Start with http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/examples-opengl.html - but really all these examples should be available after installing QT. PS: Forget GLUT, it is better to use QT instead for designing all the UI stuff and OpenGL for the 3d visualization.

Comment: Where can I get help/documentation about that?

Comment: Can you be more specific? For QT-related stuff you can become a member of the [Developer Network](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/forums/). And of course there is always stackoverflow where you can submit your specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems its plain old OpenGL, just use QGLWidget for displaying rendered results instead of any other GUI element. Any OpenGL tutorial will do then.